# Fit title text on a tabbedpage xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Hello friends how are you?
I tell you that I have a tabbedpage that aims to show a list of elements. These elements have different states and not to saturate a listview, I decided to create a tab for each state. This works well, the only problem is that the text of the tabs titles are cut. I understand that it is because of the screen size. But I have seen apps that have multiple tabs that are hidden and when they press other tabs they appear.
In summary, how can I make the text appear complete in the tab titles? Try WidthRequest, but this does not work. I thank you for the help you can give me.

```
 <ContentPage Title="Tab 1"  MinimumWidthRequest="222" WidthRequest="222" />
 <ContentPage Title="Tab 2"  MinimumWidthRequest="222" WidthRequest="222" />
 <ContentPage Title="Tab 3"  MinimumWidthRequest="222" WidthRequest="222" />
```

[image: xa]

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to make the selected tab item text to fit and the other ones hide/short?

Comment: I want the text of the tabs to be displayed full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reset the `app:tabMode` from "fixed" to "scrollable".

In Xamarin.forms, Android> Resources> layout> Tabbar.xml:

**Change:**

```
app:tabMode="fixed"
```

[image]

**To:**

```
app:tabMode="scrollable"
```

[image]

Please make sure you have the code below in your MainActivity.

```
  TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
```